# How to replace value inside XML in tasks pipeline using variables?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I update the `filename` attribute below using a variable?

I added a Replace Transmission task, but how to update the values (`filename="y.zip"`, based on my variable) inside an .xml file using pipeline tasks?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configdata>
  <solutions>
    <configsolutionfile filename="x.zip" />
  </solutions>
</configdata>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few options:

- [token replace task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)
- [XML transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xmltransform)
- [XML variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xmltransform)

It all actually depends at which stage you want to achieve and what you have already. If you want to do it before generating package I would recommend first option - token replace. If you want to do it after (= just before publishing the package) and you have already config transformation files, you can go with XML transformation. Last one is convinient if you don't want to use tranformation files and you want to do it just before publishing the package.

Answer (score 0):

Krzysztof Madej is correct. And I would also like to add the following points.

1. Here is an extension: [XDT Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.xdttransform). This extension contains the "XDT Transform" task. This task also supports to transform XML file transformation.
2. You also could try to use "[File transform](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/FileTransformV2/README.md) " task.
3. If you want to deploy the application to Azure or IIS , the [Azure App Service 
   Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) and [IIS Web App Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops) support [file transforms and variable 
   substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic).

Hope this helps.